# Unexpected behaviour when extending an ItemView in Backbone Marionette

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have something like this:

```
MyView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

templateHelpers: function () {
    return {
        imageName: function () {
            var img = this.name.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_");
            return img;
        }
    }
},
myFunc: function() {//something}

//lots of other stuff


})

MySecondView = MyView.extend({

    myFunc: function() {//something}

})
```

The motive for doing this is that I want to over-write the function myFunc in  a second use of the ItemView, but otherwise it is the same.

The issue I am finding is that I have to re-declare the templateHelpers property in MySecondView - otherwise I get an error about imageName() not defined. I was not expecting this. If I 'extend' it surely it should be there. But, then, I am not sure what 'extend' is here. I don't think it is the jQuery extend.

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly call the initialize function of the object prototype you are extending. Inheritance won't automatically occur like you may be familiar with in other languages

So in your `MySecondView` object's initialize function you'll need to insert the line:

```
MyView.prototype.initialize.call(this);
```

**Update**

Because the Marionette `templateHelpers` (when its a function) is automatically called by the view when it's instantiated, you'll need to merge all of the return values down the prototype chain. Marionette won't do this automatically. So in your case, you'll want to do something like this in `MySecondView`:

```
MySecondView = MyView.extend({

    myFunc: function() {//something}

    templateHelpers: function () {
        return  _.extend({ localHelper: function() { 
                                              // something interesting
                             }}, MyView.prototype.templateHelpers.call(this));

    },

})
```

I added a `localHelper` template helper in the derived view which extends the inherited templateHelpers return object as an example. It would be nice if the derived view just called the base (super) objects function, but it doesn't work that way. This approach, whilst not what you expected, does allow you to inherit helpers from inherited views and add to them in the derived view. For most functions that you add to your view yourself, you won't need to do this. However there are the inbuilt view functions cases like this one, `initialize`, `events` etc, which you need to manage in this way.

Comment: Thanks. I see the logic. But this does not fix it. The initialize function is called in MySecondView but the error (can't find the templateHelper) occurs before initialise is run in the 'parent'. Initialize is never fired in the parent.

Comment: Ah I see this is a special case because of the way the Marionette view works. I'll update my answer.

Comment: templateHelpers doesn't exist on the prototype of MyView at the point that templateHelpers is called in MySecondView. (Again; initialize hasn't been called yet on MyView?) ... Do I need to do something in MyView to make it so templateHelpers is put on it - like my custom functions?